# I used the correct code but still this returning false

Tags: php, pdo

```
SIGNUP.PHP/HTML
<?php
    require_once("connections/db.php");

    $error = array();
    if($user->is_loggedin())
    {
        $user->redirect('index.php');
    }

    if(isset($_POST['signup-btn']))
    {
      $username = $_POST['signup-username'];
      $password = $_POST['signup-password'];
      $email = $_POST['signup-email'];

      if($user='')
      {
          $error[] = "Please enter a username";
      }
      else if($pass='')
      {
          $error[] = "Please enter a password";
      }
      else if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
      {
          $error[] = "Please enter a valid email address";
      }
      else
   {
      try
      {
            if($user->register($username, $password, $email))
            {
                echo "registered";
            }
     }
     catch(PDOException $e)
     {
        echo $e->getMessage();
     }
  }
    }
   ?>
```

class.user.php

```
<?php
class USER{

    private $db;

    function __construct($db_con)
    {
        $this->db = $db_con;
    }

    public function register($username,$password,$email)
    {
        try
        {
          $protected_password = password_hash($upass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
          $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(username,password,email)
          VALUES(:username, :password, :email)");

           $stmt->bindparam(":username", $username);
           $stmt->bindparam(":password", $protected_password);
           $stmt->bindparam(":email", $email);
           $stmt->execute();

           return $stmt;
        }

        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function is_loggedin()
    {
        if (isset($_SESSION['user_session']))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function redirect($url)
    {
        header("Location: $url");
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        session_destroy();
        unset($_SESSION['user_session']);
        return true;
    }
}


?>
```

db.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$connection = parse_ini_file('config.ini');

try{
    $db_con = new PDO("mysql:host={$connection['host']}; dbname={$connection['dbname']}", $connection['username'], $connection['password']);
    $db_con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}

catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}


include_once 'class.user.php';
$user = new USER($db_con);
?>
```

I keep receiving the error Fatal error: Call to a member function register() on string in C:\xampp\we\signup.php on line 32

I'm completely new to PDO's.  and I can't see why this is not working.
I tried changing the code up as much as I could, but this error doesn't change.  I'm sure it's a simple stupid problem i'm overlooking as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We start out setting `$username` from your form

```
$username = $_POST['signup-username'];
```

Then I assume an equality check was meant to happen on this variable (`$username == ''`?) but instead `$user` is set to an empty string.

```
if($user='')
{
    $error[] = "Please enter a username";
}
```

Afterwards, `$user->register()` is called, and `$user` is still a string instead of an instance of your class `USER`.

Be careful that you dont put in variable assignments where you meant to put in equality checks elsewhere! I do it all the time.

```
if($user='')
{
    $error[] = "Please enter a username";
}
else if($pass='') // should this be $password == ''?
{
    $error[] = "Please enter a password";
}
```